# 'ntpdate <server URL>' doesn't change the result of '$date'

Tags: ntp

I'm trying to change my ubuntu time to French time using NTP in Ubuntu.
I typed `ntpdate <French NTP server>` as root like below.
[image]

then I checked if it works through `ntpd -p`
[image]

It seemed to work well, but when I typed `date` to check my local time
[image]

The time was still Korean one.(The real local time here is KST, that's right)

I also tried to change `/etc/ntp.conf` manually, but it didn't work as well! 
[image]

 This is my `/etc/ntp.conf` file. 

I edited this file like this, started `ntpd`, and could see NTP server was changed through `ntpq -p` like second snapshots, but my ubuntu time stuck with the Korean time.

 How could I see the result of `date` changed to French using NTP library ???

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Your question is unclear "How could I see the result of date changed to French using NTP library ???"

Answer (score 0):

NTP only changes time, it does not change your current timezone (since it does not have enough information to do that).

To change the timezone run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

then choose `Europe -> Paris` there then restart a machine.

Comment: Then what is NTP used for? If I change NTP server time what is affected from that?

Comment: @Kim the time is affected, the timezone is not.

Answer (score 0):

I finally could change my current timezone with NTP by executing

`rdate -s <ntp server address>`

Thanks.